# Typescript mocking named export singleton class in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a very simple class (GraphQlProxy) which I am instantiating as singleton (graphQlProxyService) and exporting as a named module, and I am trying to mock a public method () with Jest but I am troubles doing this.

Below is the class and test module:

```js
class GraphQlProxy {
  public async request(req: NextApiRequest) {
    if (!req.body) return new Error('The request body cannot be empty!')
    ...
  }
}

export const graphQlProxyService = new GraphQlProxy()
```

```js
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http'
import graphql from './graphql'

describe('when there is an error with the request', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('@services/graphql-proxy.service', () => ({
      graphQlProxyService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        request: () => {
          throw new Error()
        }
      }))
    }))
  })
  it('returns status code 500', async () => {
    const { req, res } = createMocks({
      method: 'POST',
      body: {},
    })
    await graphql(req, res)
    expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(500)
  })
})
```

The test currently fails because it's hitting the real endpoint rather than the desired `request` method.

I've spent a few hours on this one and I am stumped!